# header_image not returning header image url

Tags: theme-development, custom-header, header-image

I have following setup:

//set defaults

```
$args = array(
        'default-image'          => get_template_directory_uri().'/images/banner.png',
        'random-default'         => false,
        'width'                  => 960,
        'height'                 => 100,
        'flex-height'            => true,
        'flex-width'             => true,
    );
```

//enable it

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );
```

//use it

```
<img src="<?php header_image();?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="" />
```

But the `src` attribute of the image is empty string:

```
<img src="" height="100" width="960" alt="">
```

But if I hardcode the image src using

```
get_template_directory_uri().'/images/banner.png'
```

it works fine. I am not able to find the things I am missing. Thank you

Comment: `header_image()` only returns the url, you need to print it; https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/header_image

Comment: @Michael: I have tried that too

Answer (score 2):

As @Michael says, `header_image()` *returns* the URL, you need to echo it:

```
<img src="<?php echo esc_url( header_image() ) ?>" ...
```

Comment: Did exactly that, but still same result.